# How to access Safari Bookmarks from terminal

Tags: terminal, safari

Is it possible using Terminal to get all bookmarks in Safari saved to a file?

Comment: They are all in `~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist`. Have you explored using that? Needs a script to extract the xml fields you want for each record. So certainly possible.

Comment: Or have you used Safari > File > Export> Bookmarks to produce an html file with all bookmarks? Then manipulate that into whatever form you want.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. But of course `cat: /Users/williamentriken/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist: Operation not permitted` because Mac.